# VBA - Retrieve multiple RecordSets from SQL query

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

I have a Stored Procedure on the SQL Server and I pull the results via VBA (Library: MS ActiveX Data Objects Library, ADODB).

Everything works fine when I only expect the query to return the result for 1 SELECT statement.
Now the Query consists of 5 SELECT statements and I want get all records from each recordset to be put into an array so I can work with the data. I am not able to do so, please help me further.

SQL Query results look like this in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

I tried different approaches in VBA, but non is working and will lead to different errors.
Error Numbers are either "3251", "3704" or "91".

This is my function to put the results into a RecordSet:

```
Function getAnalysisInformationFromDB(ByRef rs As Recordset, ByVal sSQL As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open conString
    Set rs = cnn.Execute(sSQL)
    rs.MoveFirst
    getAnalysisInformationFromDB = True
    Exit Function
    
errHandler:
    Dim sErrMsg As String
    If Err Then
        If Not cnn Is Nothing Then
            If cnn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To cnn.Errors.Count - 1 Step 1
                    sErrMsg = sErrMsg & cnn.Errors.Item(i) & vbCrLf
                Next
            End If
        End If
        If sErrMsg = "" Then
            If Err.Number = 3021 Then
                sErrMsg = "AnalysisID not found in DB"
            Else
                sErrMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
            End If
        
        End If
    End If
    If sErrMsg <> "" Then
        MsgBox sErrMsg, vbCritical
    End If

    If Not cnn Is Nothing Then
        If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close
    End If
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Function
```

Different approaches no look like this:

```
Sub getData()
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "confidential" ' --> SQL Connection String etc...

    Dim rsAnalysis
    If Not getAnalysisInformationFromDB(rsAnalysis, sSQL) = True Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim vHeader() As Variant
    Dim vData() As Variant
    
    Dim rsTemp
    Do Until rsAnalysis Is Nothing
        Set rsTemp = rsAnalysis.NextRecordset()
        vData = rsTemp.GetRows
        
        '   Do something with the Array...
        '   ...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Or (here it does not even jump to the error handler, eventhough an error occurs...):

```
Sub getData2()
    Dim rsAnalysis
    If Not getAnalysisInformationFromDB(rsAnalysis, sSQL) = True Then Exit Sub
    
    Do Until rsAnalysis Is Nothing
        rsAnalysis.MoveFirst
        On Error GoTo check_RS
        Dim iCount As Integer: iCount = -1
        For Each s In rsAnalysis.Fields
            iCount = iCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve vHeader(iCount): vHeader(iCount) = s.name
            
        Next
        If Not rsAnalysis.BOF And Not rsAnalysis.EOF Then
            vData = rsAnalysis.GetRows
        End If
        
        Stop
        Erase vHeader
retry_RS:
        Set rsAnalysis = rsAnalysis.NextRecordset()
    Loop
    
    
check_RS:
    If Err Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number
        If Err.Number = 91 Or Err.Number = 3704 Or Err.Number = 3251 Then
            GoTo retry_RS
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

edit: the error always happens when I try to hand over the recordset to the array variable (vData = rsAnalysis.GetRows)

Comment: I'd start by disabling your error handlers so you can more-easily see where the errors are happening.

Comment: Also - if you're getting errors it's useful to show the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was, that SQL Server creates messages after the query ran. I had to "SET NOCOUNT ON;" and now only the recordsets are being handed over to VBA and everything works as expected.